# What case can be brought against a former employer for unpaid wages?

Tags: employment, salary, philippines

In the Philippines, what case can be brought against an employer who has not paid its employees?

What kind of case would that be, and would it be with the Department of Labor and Employment ([DOLE](https://www.dole.gov.ph/))?

Comment: https://lawyerphilippines.org/philippine-free-legal-advice-groups/